# what's the meaning of "\374" in 0x5107ba0 "\374\003xxx" (watch of eclipse)

Tags: c, watch

When I am debugging a C program, and watch a pointer to a string, in the watch window of eclipse, the value is  0x5107ba0 "\374\003xxx"
So I think 0x5107ba0 is the address of the pointer. "\003" means the 0x03, but what is "\374"? one byte has a maximum of 255, so 374 need more than one byte to store.

Or "\374" mean octal 374?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's octal. It's 252, or 0xfc. Octal has a maximum value of 0377 in 8 bits.

Comment: My question is, why is it octal, and can it be changed to hex instead?